# GET call from Angular frontend to json-server Access to XMLHttpRequest blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, json, google-chrome, get, cors

i have an angular frontend client on my localhost and trying to make a GET call to a json-server also running on my localhost to get some data due filling a table on a view.

the table still empty and i get this error on chrome console:

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:3000/cilas' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https."

added header attribute 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' but got no result, i've also enabled  cross origin resource sharing on google chrome by installing an add-on, server side i just run json-server --watch src/data/document.json so didn't writed any code just put some data on the file document, but the problem seems to be on client side.

//here's the call and the header client side:

headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        });

return this.http.get(pathUrl, { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json());

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED.

my url have to be:
'http://localhost:3000/cilas'

instead of:
'localhost:3000/cilas'

wrongly supposed that http was implicit...